# Chitted Potatoes Lifespan

Tags: potatoes

I chitted more seed potatoes today that I had room for in my raised bed and am wondering:

How long will they keep before I have to plant them?

In other words, will they go bad?

Thanks!

doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop them from growing now they have started. They won't "go bad" but they will shrivel up and eventually die.

If you keep them in the dark you will just get long white shoots. If you keep them in the light they will start developing leaves.

If you can't plant them somewhere in the next two or three weeks at most, either throw them away or give them to somebody else who has room for them.

Note, you can grow potatoes in grow-bags. Google will find plenty of advice.

Comment: Thanks so much.. Maybe i'll go ahead and build another raised bed this weekend and plant them..Thanks again